# Add events for before/after a action of a controller in Magento

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, magento

I have a controller in Magento as below:

```
#File: ./app/local/FilFact/Test/IndexController
class FilFact_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->_testConfig();
    }
}
```

I need to add two events for:
***`before`*** `index action`
***`after`*** `index action`

How could I do that?

Comment: You would like to provide the two events so that other modules can hook into them, is that right?

Comment: Yes, And I use a way like:  Add the statement: `Mage::dispatchEvent('test_index_index_before_action',$data);` inside the index action. But it's not good. The below answer is more better.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is simple as the Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action base class provides pre/post dispatch events.

If you open up the Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action class you find two methods: [preDispatch()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/a1aca1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L527-L531) and [postDispatch()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/a1aca1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L543-L551)

These method perform a few tasks and most importantly fire off three events.

```
controller_action_(pre|post)dispatch
controller_action_(pre|post)dispatch_{{routeName}}
controller_action_(pre|post)dispatch_{{fullActionName}}
```

The fullActionName is the route name, the controller name, and the action name separated by '_' and all lower case. (See [Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::getFullActionName](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/a1aca1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L224-L229) for reference)

/app/code/local/FilFact/Test/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <FilFact_Test>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        <FilFact_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <FilFact_Test>
                <class>FilFact_Test_Model</class>
            </FilFact_Test>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <filfact>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>FilFact_Test</module>
                    <frontName>filfact</frontName>
                </args>
            </filfact>
        </routers>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_filfact_index_index>
                <observers>
                    <FilFact_Test>
                        <class>FilFact_Test/Observer</class>
                        <method>indexPreDispatch</method>
                    </FilFact_Test>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_filfact_index_index>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_filfact_index_index>
                <observers>
                    <FilFact_Test>
                        <class>FilFact_Test/Observer</class>
                        <method>indexPostDispatch</method>
                    </FilFact_Test>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_filfact_index_index>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/FilFact/Test/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class FilFact_Test_Model_Observer
{
    public function indexPreDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       // TODO: Your code
    }

    public function indexPostDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       // TODO: Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try. :) Love your answer.