# How to edit a products custom options in the observer

Tags: magento, events, request

I have a problem with Magento 1.9.2.4

What I need to do is when I add a product I need to do some custom validation for the products custom options that is being added. 
Also after validation I need a possibility to edit those options.

I have tried these events

```
catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add
```

But there is no result, also after researching on google I have tried to edit request and set my params but there are still no results.

Does anyone have a solution? Or maybe I could use another event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution here [Add events for before/after a action of a controller in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510293/add-events-for-before-after-a-action-of-a-controller-in-magento).
I was using wrong event. Needed to use predispatch

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to observe product model itself?
This event will allow you to compare the old and the new product values:

```
catalog_product_save_before
```

And here you can do whatever you like just before product is saved

```
catalog_product_save_after
```

You can even prevent actually update DB data by throwing an exception as you can see in a core code below ($this->_afterSave())

```
/* Mage_Core_Model_Abstract */
try {
        $this->_beforeSave();
        if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
            $this->_getResource()->save($this);
            $this->_afterSave();
        }
        $this->_getResource()->addCommitCallback(array($this, 'afterCommitCallback'))
            ->commit();
        $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
        $dataCommited = true;
} catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getResource()->rollBack();
        $this->_hasDataChanges = true;
        throw $e;
}

catalog_product_save_after
```

If you want to be sure that your product is saved and you want to do some additional work try this:

```
catalog_product_save_commit_after
```