# Magento add an postDispatch to a post action

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have this controller :

```
class Mage_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();

    if( !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED) ) {
        $this->norouteAction();
    }
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('juron/ses');
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function postAction()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ( $post ) {
        ......
    }
 }
}
```

In the `/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.yml` :

```
<events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_post_action>
            <observers>
                <contacts>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>contacts/observer</class>
                    <method>postDispatch</method>
                <contacts>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_post_action>
    </events>
```

And in `/Mage/Contacts/Model/Observer.php` :

```
class Mage_Contacts_Model_Observer
{
    public function postDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        echo 'Stop';
        die();
    }
}
```

Normally when I try to submit the contact form I shoul see `Stop` and the execution should be finished but not work like this. Seems the observer is not called. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add events for before/after a action of a controller in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510293/add-events-for-before-after-a-action-of-a-controller-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

The right event to listen to here would be `controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post`.
The structure is `controller_action_postdispatch_ROUTER_CONTROLLERNAME_ACTIONNAME`.

P.S. : acknowledge that you should write your module in the local pool and not in the core.